# Deadlock in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, database-deadlocks

I am getting deadlock while running the below queries in Oracle

```
update MYTABLE 
   set COLUMN1 = COLUMN1 + 589 
 where COLUMN1 >= 7988 
   and COLUMN1 <= 7988

update MYTABLE 
   set COLUMN1 = COLUMN1 + 660 
 where COLUMN1 >= 7840
```

How come I will get a deadlock when both the queries are running in 2 separate Transactions?
My point is the second query will wait until the first query finishes its Transaction when the isolation is set to `READCOMMITTED` right?

Is there any hint I can apply to avoid deadlock?

Note: `COLUMN1` is not a PK in that table, however application ensures that there are no duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Since both the windows are overlapping, I think there might be the issue. Oracle locks the same blocks for the two queries, thus giving problems when executing at the same time.

Also, check the [answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691537/is-a-deadlock-possible-when-updating-and-deleting-different-rows-in-a-table) on SO.

Check on there the lock occurs by checking the `dba_lock` table. See docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_4111.htm#REFRN23116).

Comment: But if the first transaction locks the whole table, won't the second just block until the first releases those locks?

Comment: @AlexPoole: I think you are right, unless Oracle locks on block level.

Comment: No, Patrick, in this situation(`where` clause is present), the entire table will not be locked, only subset of rows will be. Second, presence or absence of an index won't help to avoid deadlock in this situation(presence of an index might help when there is a master\detail relationship between tables and the index created on a foreign key column)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, those statements you've presented can produce deadlock. One of the simplest scenario would be:

1. Session 1 issues first  `update` statement;
2. Session 2 issues second `update` statement;
3. Session 1 issues second `update` statement;

Example:

```
-- Session #1 locks a subset of rows
SQL> update mytable 
        set column1 = column1 + 589 
      where column1 >= 7988 
        and column1 <= 7988;

1 row updated.

                                           -- session #2
                                           -- trying to lock subset of rows
                                           -- locked by the first session update
                                          SQL> update mytable 
                                                  set column1 = column1 + 660 
                                                where column1 >= 7840;


-- session #1
-- trying to lock subset of rows that are locked
-- by session #2 update, that in turn's
-- trying to lock the subset of rows 
-- locked by session #1 update statement
SQL> update mytable 
        set column1 = column1 + 660 
      where column1 >= 7840;


                                          -- session #2
                                          -- thus deadlock
                                          update mytable 
                                              set column1 = column1 + 660 
                                            where column1 >= 7840
                                                              *
                                          ERROR at line 1:
                        ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource
```

When you construct an `update` or `delete` statement using `where` clause, the statement becomes a two-part statement that consist of reading and writing parts. Reading part reserves rows `for update` and writing one changes them. So first session's `update` statement locks some set of data for update, changes them and keep them locked until you issue `commit` or `rollback`, second session's `update` statement locks its part of rows, and them first session is trying to lock that part of data that's being locked by the second one, thus deadlock. If you issue those updates statement in one session, there should be not dead lock whatsoever. But when you issue those update statements in more than one session simultaneously without commit or rollback, be prepared for `ORA-00060` exception.

Every deadlock is accompanied by the creation of an alert file. Check the file to get more detailed information about deadlock.

> Is there any hint I can apply to avoid deadlock?

No, there is no such hint.