# How to understand ORA-00060 deadlock trace file

Tags: oracle, database-deadlocks

Recently I got a ORA-00060 deadlock error.

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691537/is-a-deadlock-possible-when-updating-and-deleting-different-rows-in-a-table) and [this post](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/ap_locks001.htm#SQLRF55502) and [this post](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/consist.htm#CNCPT1364) but I'm not sure what the problem is: unindexed FK cause this or other problem.

My question is how to understand this trace file and how to solve it?

Below is the trace file:

```
*** 2015-06-02 14:53:45.513
DEADLOCK DETECTED ( ORA-00060 )

[Transaction Deadlock]

The following deadlock is not an ORACLE error. It is a
deadlock due to user error in the design of an application
or from issuing incorrect ad-hoc SQL. The following
information may aid in determining the deadlock:

Deadlock graph:
                       ---------Blocker(s)--------  ---------Waiter(s)---------
Resource Name          process session holds waits  process session holds waits
TM-00014d94-00000000       497     556           S      332    1414          SX
TM-00014d94-00000000       332    1414          SX      416    1038           S
TX-0011000f-000000ab       416    1038     X            302     457           S
TM-00014d94-00000000       302     457    SX            497     556           S

session 556: DID 0001-01F1-0000000D session 1414: DID 0001-014C-00000022 
session 1414: DID 0001-014C-00000022    session 1038: DID 0001-01A0-0000000C 
session 1038: DID 0001-01A0-0000000C    session 457: DID 0001-012E-00000028 
session 457: DID 0001-012E-00000028 session 556: DID 0001-01F1-0000000D 

Rows waited on:
  Session 556: obj - rowid = 00014D94 - AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
  (dictionary objn - 85396, file - 0, block - 0, slot - 0)
  Session 1414: obj - rowid = 00014D94 - AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
  (dictionary objn - 85396, file - 0, block - 0, slot - 0)
  Session 1038: obj - rowid = 00014D94 - AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
  (dictionary objn - 85396, file - 0, block - 0, slot - 0)
  Session 457: obj - rowid = 00014FA0 - AAAU+gAAEAAAft+AAA
  (dictionary objn - 85920, file - 4, block - 129918, slot - 0)

----- Information for the OTHER waiting sessions -----
Session 1414:
  sid: 1414 ser: 1424 audsid: 100128 user: 91/SW flags: 0x45
  pid: 332 O/S info: user: oracle, term: UNKNOWN, ospid: 10179
    image: oracle@jwdb
  client details:
    O/S info: user: root, term: unknown, ospid: 1234
    machine: localhost.localdomain program: JDBC Thin Client
    application name: JDBC Thin Client, hash value=2546894660
  current SQL:
  insert into t_course_takes (created_at, updated_at, attend, course_id, course_take_type_id, election_mode_id, lesson_id, limit_group_id, paid, remark, semester_id, state, std_id, turn, virtual_cost, id) values (:1 , :2 , :3 , :4 , :5 , :6 , :7 , :8 , :9 , :10 , :11 , :12 , :13 , :14 , :15 , :16 )

Session 1038:
  sid: 1038 ser: 951 audsid: 100212 user: 91/SW flags: 0x45
  pid: 416 O/S info: user: oracle, term: UNKNOWN, ospid: 10343
    image: oracle@jwdb
  client details:
    O/S info: user: root, term: unknown, ospid: 1234
    machine: localhost.localdomain program: JDBC Thin Client
    application name: JDBC Thin Client, hash value=2546894660
  current SQL:
  delete from t_course_takes where id=:1 

Session 457:
  sid: 457 ser: 2983 audsid: 100099 user: 91/SW flags: 0x45
  pid: 302 O/S info: user: oracle, term: UNKNOWN, ospid: 10111
    image: oracle@jwdb
  client details:
    O/S info: user: root, term: unknown, ospid: 1234
    machine: jdbcclient program: JDBC Thin Client
    application name: JDBC Thin Client, hash value=2546894660
  current SQL:
  insert into t_elect_loggers (created_at, updated_at, course_code, course_name, course_take_type_id, course_type, credits, election_mode_id, ip_address, lesson_no, operator_code, operator_name, project_id, remark, screening, semester_id, std_code, std_name, turn, type, virtual_orig, virtual_rest, id) values (:1 , :2 , :3 , :4 , :5 , :6 , :7 , :8 , :9 , :10 , :11 , :12 , :13 , :14 , :15 , :16 , :17 , :18 , :19 , :20 , :21 , :22 , :23 )

----- End of information for the OTHER waiting sessions -----

Information for THIS session:

----- Current SQL Statement for this session (sql_id=ca9jc1g44ap41) -----
delete from t_course_takes where id=:1 
===================================================
PROCESS STATE
-------------
Process global information:
     process: 0x9d0fd98c8, call: 0x95429a500, xact: 0x922b10710, curses: 0x94110e198, usrses: 0x94110e198
  ----------------------------------------
  SO: 0x9d0fd98c8, type: 2, owner: (nil), flag: INIT/-/-/0x00 if: 0x3 c: 0x3
   proc=0x9d0fd98c8, name=process, file=ksu.h LINE:11459, pg=0
  (process) Oracle pid:497, ser:7, calls cur/top: 0x95429a500/0x95429a500
            flags : (0x0) -
            flags2: (0x0),  flags3: (0x0) 
            intr error: 0, call error: 0, sess error: 0, txn error 0
            intr queue: empty
  ksudlp FALSE at location: 0
  (post info) last post received: 0 0 9
              last post received-location: ksq.h LINE:1877 ID:ksqrcl
              last process to post me: 900fd0348 12 0
              last post sent: 0 0 9
              last post sent-location: ksq.h LINE:1877 ID:ksqrcl
              last process posted by me: 900fce2c8 17 0
    (latch info) wait_event=0 bits=0
    Process Group: DEFAULT, pseudo proc: 0x90102ea98
    O/S info: user: oracle, term: UNKNOWN, ospid: 10507 
    OSD pid info: Unix process pid: 10507, image: oracle@jwdb
Dump of memory from 0x0000000921009C90 to 0x0000000921009E98
921009C90 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  [................]
        Repeat 31 times
921009E90 00000000 00000000                    [........]        
    (FOB) flags=2050 fib=0x902c3c2b8 incno=0 pending i/o cnt=0
     fname=/home/jwdb/oracle/oradata/orcl/undotbs01.dbf
     fno=3 lblksz=8192 fsiz=238080
    (FOB) flags=2050 fib=0x902c3c8b8 incno=0 pending i/o cnt=0
     fname=/home/jwdb/oracle/oradata/orcl/users01.dbf
     fno=4 lblksz=8192 fsiz=603680
    (FOB) flags=2050 fib=0x902c3b6a0 incno=0 pending i/o cnt=0
     fname=/home/jwdb/oracle/oradata/orcl/system01.dbf
     fno=1 lblksz=8192 fsiz=92160
    ----------------------------------------
    SO: 0x94110e198, type: 4, owner: 0x9d0fd98c8, flag: INIT/-/-/0x00 if: 0x3 c: 0x3
     proc=0x9d0fd98c8, name=session, file=ksu.h LINE:11467, pg=0
    (session) sid: 556 ser: 3224 trans: 0x922b10710, creator: 0x9d0fd98c8
              flags: (0x45) USR/- flags_idl: (0x1) BSY/-/-/-/-/-
              flags2: (0x40008) -/-
              DID: , short-term DID: 
              txn branch: (nil)
              oct: 7, prv: 0, sql: 0x9cfed0be0, psql: 0x9afeb20c8, user: 91/SW
    ksuxds FALSE at location: 0
    service name: SYS$USERS
    client details:
      O/S info: user: root, term: unknown, ospid: 1234
      machine: localhost.localdomain program: JDBC Thin Client
      application name: JDBC Thin Client, hash value=2546894660
    Current Wait Stack:
     0: waiting for 'enq: TM - contention'
        name|mode=0x544d0004, object #=0x14d94, table/partition=0x0
        wait_id=787 seq_num=896 snap_id=53
        wait times: snap=0.023828 sec, exc=4 min 18 sec, total=4 min 18 sec
        wait times: max=infinite, heur=4 min 18 sec
        wait counts: calls=87 os=87
        in_wait=1 iflags=0x15a0
    There is at least one session blocking this session.
      Dumping first 3 direct blockers:
        inst: 1, sid: 457, ser: 2983
        inst: 1, sid: 1353, ser: 5618
        inst: 1, sid: 907, ser: 5215
      Dumping final blocker:
        inst: 1, sid: 1168, ser: 1194
    There are 1 sessions blocked by this session.
    Dumping one waiter:
      inst: 1, sid: 1136, ser: 2212
      wait event: 'enq: TM - contention'
        p1: 'name|mode'=0x544d0004
        p2: 'object #'=0x14d94
        p3: 'table/partition'=0x0
      row_wait_obj#: 85396, block#: 0, row#: 0, file# 0
      min_blocked_time: 12 secs, waiter_cache_ver: 32536
    Wait State:
      fixed_waits=0 flags=0x23 boundary=(nil)/-1
    Session Wait History:
        elapsed time of 0.000000 sec since current wait
     0: waited for 'latch: enqueue hash chains'
        address=0x9313226a0, number=0x1c, tries=0x0
        wait_id=839 seq_num=895 snap_id=1
        wait times: snap=0.226082 sec, exc=0.226082 sec, total=0.226082 sec
        wait times: max=infinite
        wait counts: calls=0 os=0
        occurred after 0.000000 sec of elapsed time
     1: waited for 'enq: TM - contention'
        name|mode=0x544d0004, object #=0x14d94, table/partition=0x0
        wait_id=787 seq_num=894 snap_id=52
        wait times: snap=3.000901 sec, exc=4 min 18 sec, total=4 min 18 sec
        wait times: max=infinite
        wait counts: calls=87 os=87
        occurred after 0.000000 sec of elapsed time
     2: waited for 'latch: enqueue hash chains'
        address=0x6000cf38, number=0x1c, tries=0x0
        wait_id=838 seq_num=893 snap_id=1
        wait times: snap=0.000142 sec, exc=0.000142 sec, total=0.000142 sec
        wait times: max=infinite
        wait counts: calls=0 os=0
        occurred after 0.000000 sec of elapsed time
     3: waited for 'enq: TM - contention'
        name|mode=0x544d0004, object #=0x14d94, table/partition=0x0
        wait_id=787 seq_num=892 snap_id=51
        wait times: snap=12.003822 sec, exc=4 min 15 sec, total=4 min 15 sec
        wait times: max=infinite
        wait counts: calls=86 os=86
        occurred after 0.000000 sec of elapsed time
     4: waited for 'latch: enqueue hash chains'
        address=0x6000cf38, number=0x1c, tries=0x0
        wait_id=837 seq_num=891 snap_id=1
        wait times: snap=0.000170 sec, exc=0.000170 sec, total=0.000170 sec
        wait times: max=infinite
        wait counts: calls=0 os=0
        occurred after 0.000000 sec of elapsed time
     5: waited for 'enq: TM - contention'
        name|mode=0x544d0004, object #=0x14d94, table/partition=0x0
        wait_id=787 seq_num=890 snap_id=50
        wait times: snap=6.001627 sec, exc=4 min 3 sec, total=4 min 3 sec
        wait times: max=infinite
        wait counts: calls=82 os=82
        occurred after 0.000000 sec of elapsed time
     6: waited for 'latch: enqueue hash chains'
        address=0x6000cf38, number=0x1c, tries=0x0
        wait_id=836 seq_num=889 snap_id=1
        wait times: snap=0.000378 sec, exc=0.000378 sec, total=0.000378 sec
        wait times: max=infinite
        wait counts: calls=0 os=0
        occurred after 0.000000 sec of elapsed time
     7: waited for 'enq: TM - contention'
        name|mode=0x544d0004, object #=0x14d94, table/partition=0x0
        wait_id=787 seq_num=888 snap_id=49
        wait times: snap=3.000543 sec, exc=3 min 57 sec, total=3 min 57 sec
        wait times: max=infinite
        wait counts: calls=80 os=80
        occurred after 0.000000 sec of elapsed time
     8: waited for 'latch: enqueue hash chains'
        address=0x6000cf38, number=0x1c, tries=0x0
        wait_id=835 seq_num=887 snap_id=1
        wait times: snap=0.000350 sec, exc=0.000350 sec, total=0.000350 sec
        wait times: max=infinite
        wait counts: calls=0 os=0
        occurred after 0.000000 sec of elapsed time
     9: waited for 'enq: TM - contention'
        name|mode=0x544d0004, object #=0x14d94, table/partition=0x0
        wait_id=787 seq_num=886 snap_id=48
        wait times: snap=3.000880 sec, exc=3 min 54 sec, total=3 min 54 sec
        wait times: max=infinite
        wait counts: calls=79 os=79
        occurred after 0.000000 sec of elapsed time
```

---

**Updated on 6/5/2015**

The whole trace file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0y4htr4wnlrv0s8/orcl_ora_10507.trc?dl=0)

Comment: I do not think you have problems with un-indexed FKs. In such a case you would hava lock type SSX in your report. See Oracle lock modes https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2010/06/21/locks/. SSX applies to the situation when Oracle validating FK constraint does not have any other option then to lock the whole table.

Comment: Does your trace file have any section talking about cursors? Cursor is a place of execution for a SQL statement. And you could see values of bind variables in Cursors section.

Comment: Thank you very much @ibre5041 . The trace file is 1.8M, so I just paste a part of it in this question. The whole trace file is here, https://www.dropbox.com/s/0y4htr4wnlrv0s8/orcl_ora_10507.trc?dl=0

Comment: Do you have any bitmap indexes on those tables?  They can sometimes cause deadlocks even if the rows changed are unrelated.

Comment: @JonHeller thank you for reply. There are not bitmap index on those tables. All indexes is type of NORMAL.

Answer (score 0):

This ORA-00060 was causing problem to my team also. The trace file was showing the blocking of two session each other as TX--- X --------S. In our case we were sure that the multithreaded environment is distributed on unique_number column such that two threads will not update the same record. Further down the trace file it showed "enq: TX - allocate ITL entry". When the processing was running I checked the kind of waits:

```
select blocking_session, sid, serial#, wait_class, seconds_in_wait
from
v$session
where
blocking_session is not NULL
order by
blocking_session;
```

And it was showing the wait class is "Configure". So, I increased the initrans of the tables used by the processing. Then also reduced the batch size so that commit happens more frequently then earlier. After that the problem is solved.